# Isn't UNIX_TIMESTAMP universally the same? My server time is 5 seconds ahead

Tags: javascript, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a node js server using socket.io and I need it to send me the "end time" of the items to display on my website. As soon as the `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)` on the client browser hits the end time then the item should vanish from the site.

The problem is when I fetch `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` from MySQL database.

I need the client to display the seconds left so it needs to calculate the difference client-side, but the MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP is 5 seconds ahead, it's giving me a lot of pain to figure out why. Isn't Unix Timestamp the same in all over the world?

Comment: you client is off. clocks drift. most hosted servers get resynced often, but it really should not matter for the purpose of computing duration if one of the clocks is offset, so long as they tick as fast as eachother... all you need to do is send the server timestamp along with the SQL-stored timestamp, then subtract the two to tell exactly how long the difference is (minus 1-way HTTP lag, which is typically negligable)

Comment: [No.](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time)

Comment: So how can I display how much time left untill the database stored time if I can't find an universal time value?

Comment: @Steven The article in the link was written from a arrogant developer. Even the first point is scientific absolutly true.

Comment: Calculate the offset between client and server time and always rely on the server time, never on the client. Which means, your client dide scripts regularly have to check back to the server to confirm the time elapsed. When the server thinks it is time to remove a content, then remove it.

Comment: @steven #23 on that list is my favorite. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was simple:
I make the math on the server before sending to client the result, `<database stored time> - <server time>`
this way all the clients will see the same timer value.
I made this answer so anyone who has the same problem can find the solution.
=]

Comment: A better solution is to synchronize the clocks on the systems.  Check out NTP.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer You generally can't force that on clients. (Unfortunately!)

Comment: @duskwuff the way I'm doing it will work, right? Or is there some kind of problem that may occur?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca Yes, what you're doing is essentially correct. There are some enhancements that can be made (like resynchronizing the time periodically), but it'll work quite well as is.